# Why can't we set the jquery selector object to another object's property and use them later?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, I'm trying to do set the jquery selector object to another object property but it's not working out. What am I getting wrong here?

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Page</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="name"></p>
    <p id="password"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript.js

```
var obj = {
    name:$('#name'),
    password:$('#password'),
    setval: function () {
        this.name.html("anand");
        this.password.html("abc@1234");
    }
};

$(document).ready(obj.setval());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the object before the elements you try to select are created and also your document.ready code is wrong.
`obj.setval()` executes the function then passed its result to `$(document).ready` as a parameter, what you want to do is pass a function as the parameter, an anonymous function is usually the easiest.

Try

```
var obj;

$(document).ready(function(){
    obj = {
    name:$('#name'),
    password:$('#password'),
    setval: function () {
        this.name.html("anand");
        this.password.html("abc@1234");
        }
    };
    obj.setval()

});
```

Comment: There's a fundamental mistake in OP's code, you forgot to explain.

Comment: So does it mean that the object creation happens at the time of script loads into browser, and not dynamically at the time of using that object?

Comment: It depends where the code is, if the object is declared in a function the object will be created when the function runs. In this case it is just in the head tag so it will be created as the script loads.

Comment: @Musa Will it makes difference if I define the obj the way I was, outside of `$(document).ready(function(){` and call the `setval()` as `new obj.setval();`. It should work, no?

Comment: Nope, it seems like you're grasping at straws. The issue is the properties `name` and `password` are set values at creation of the object which is before the DOM elements `#name` and `#password` exist. So it doesn't matter how or when you call `setval`

Answer (score 3):

This works. This is not the right way you invoke the function. The below is wrong:

```
$(document).ready(obj.setval());
```

You should use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  obj.setval();
});
```

Or, the other way is, *in case you are not using objects with `this` keyword*:

```
$(document).ready(obj.setval);
```

> The function expects a function to be executed.

**See the working snippet here:**

```js
var obj = {
  name:$('#name'),
  password:$('#password'),
  setval: function () {
    this.name.html("anand");
    this.password.html("abc@1234");
  }
};
$(document).ready(function () {
  obj.setval();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<p id="name"></p>
<p id="password"></p>
```

Comment: It would be useful to clarify how using `()` will execute a function and how without will pass a reference to the function that can be used to execute it later

Comment: `$(document).ready(obj.setval);` will not work since since op uses `this` in the function

Comment: @Musa Right! Agreed... He can give the context of function as `, this` right? Asking you... `:)`

Comment: @Musa Thanks. I clarified the use of `this`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks. But when I'm putting the script tag in my head element, its not working! In my limited knowledge, `$(document).ready();` gets called after the DOM has finished loading. It works when I put the script tag after closing body tag.

Comment: @AnandTyagi That's crazy. Not exactly sure... I am unable to replicate it.

Comment: This only works, because the SO script editor places the executed script at the end of the body tag (after the html). With the exact set up in the question, jquery selects nothting.

Comment: It's quite simple, Musas answer explains it. The elements do not exists in the DOM at the time they are *selected*.

Comment: @Yoshi So this means that the object creation happens at the time of script loads into browser, and not dynamically at the time of using that object?

Comment: @AnandTyagi Correct.

Comment: @Yoshi What if I user the `new` keyword, and then call the `setval()`? it should create it first before calling the function, right?

Comment: @AnandTyagi No, it wouldn't change a thing. The problem is that the expression `$('#name')` (and of course `$('#password')`) get's executed an the spot. Irregardless of the result being assigned to some object's property. As such the expression evaluates to *nothing useful*. You need to postpone the evaluation to some point in time when it actually is relevant, in your case, when the appropriate DOM-elements exist.